# Decode not working properly and while loop not breaking correctly python

Tags: python, sockets, tcp

This is a file transfer application using TCP sockets in Python. The file-transfer protocol will in- clude a server called ftps.py and a client called ftpc.py.

The file-transfer application will use a simple protocol. The first 4 bytes (in network byte order) will contain the number of bytes in the file to follow. The next 20 bytes will contain the name of the file (assume the name fits in 20 bytes). The rest of the bytes in the TCP stream to follow will contain the data in the file.

I am running the client program and the server program on separate machines, but i have two errors:
1) The when i encode the filename and sent it to the socket, when the server side receives it and decodes it, the filename isn't correct

2) The server side seems to be stuck in a while loop and i don't know why

Client

```
import socket
import sys
import os

filename=sys.argv[2]
print filename
if len(sys.argv) > 1 :
    print('Trying to connect...')
    s = socket.socket()
    ip_add=(sys.argv[1])
    print(ip_add)
    s.connect((ip_add, 4000))

    print('Connected. Wating for command.')
    while True:
        cmd = s.recv(24)
        if cmd == 'getsize':
            print('"getsize" command received.')
            statinfo=os.stat(filename)
            byte_size=statinfo.st_size
            size_str=str(byte_size)
            s.sendall(size_str)

        if cmd == 'getfilename':
            print('"getfilename" command received.')
        formatted_name = filename.rjust(20)
        fname = formatted_name.lstrip()
        print(fname)
        encoded_filename=fname.encode('utf-8')
            s.sendall(encoded_filename)

        if cmd == 'getfile':
            print('"getfile" command received. Going to send file.')     
            file_input = open(sys.argv[2], 'rb')
        while True:
        buff = file_input.read(512)
            if len(buff) == 0:
                break
        s.sendall(buff)

            print('File transmission done.')

        if cmd == 'end':
            print('"end" command received. Teminate.')
            break
file_input.close()
f.close()
```

Server

```
import socket
import os
import sys

save_path='recv/'


print('Waiting for clinet to connect...')
c = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
c.bind(('', 4000))
c.listen(1)
s, a = c.accept()

print('Connected. Going to receive file.')
s.sendall('getsize')
filesize_str = s.recv(4)
size_bytes=filesize_str.decode()
print(size_bytes)
s.sendall('getfilename')
byte_var = s.recv(20)
filename=byte_var.decode('utf-8')

output = os.path.join(save_path, filename)
f = open(output, 'wb')

print('Filename: ' + filename)

while True:
    s.sendall('getfile')
    while True:
        data = s.recv(512)
        if not data: 
            break
        f.write(data)
        break
s.sendall('end')
print('File received.')

s.close()
c.close()
f.close()
```

Here is the terminal output for the server program:

```
% python ftps.py
Waiting for clinet to connect...
Connected. Going to receive file.
1797
Filename: 55
```

Client output:

```
% python ftpc.py 164.107.113.20 2.jpg
2.jpg
Trying to connect...
164.107.113.20
Connected. Wating for command.
"getsize" command received.
"getfilename" command received.
2.jpg
"getfile" command received. Going to send file.
File transmission done.
```

where it says Filename: 55, it should be Filename:2.jpg
and the program is stuck in a loop at this point.. any one know why this is happening?

Comment: Your indentation looks messed up.

Comment: hmmm, in my code it seems to be indented correctly, but here is keeps messing it up

Comment: i just manually fixed it

Comment: Listening on 4000, sending at 5000? How does it even work?

Comment: both are 4000.. i posted the wrong file